# IIS URL Rewrite 404 Error

Tags: windows, iis, redirect, rewrite, url

I am running a small intranet site off Windows 7 and IIS and I have a page `page/LoadPage.aspx` which is an ASPX container page for displaying a requested page, e.g. `http://localhost/page/LoadPage.aspx?p=downloads` (which loads `downloads.html` located in the root directory).

The problem is, when creating a User-Friendly URL using the URL Rewrite plugin in IIS 7, if the query tag (`p`) requests a page in a particular directory (e.g. `http://localhost/page/LoadPage.aspx?p=downloads/software`, which should load the page `downloads/software.html`) then a 404 error will be thrown because the server thinks the user has requested a directory.

The mapping and redirecting **do** work for single requests like `page/LoadPage.aspx?p=downloads` which successfully redirects to `http://localhost/downloads.html`.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:** Here is the code. Could it be the problem?

Example URL: `/page/LoadPage.aspx?p=downloads` (This works and redirects to `downloads.html`)

Example URL: `/page/LoadPage.aspx?p=downloads/software` (This doesn't work, but is meant to redirect to `/downloads/software.html`)

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim p = Request.QueryString("p").ToString
        Dim page = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(p)
        Dim ReadHTML As New IO.StreamReader("\\PC\User\Documents\IIS Websites\Intranet\" & page & ".html")
        container.InnerHtml = ReadHTML.ReadToEnd
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`/` is a reserved character, so you will need to url encode the querystring value.

Your URL should look like this:

```
http://localhost/page/LoadPage.aspx?p=downloads%2Fsoftware
```

To use the value in your .NET code, you will need to decode the value:

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(value);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. It seems that IIS does not like `/` in a query unless it is **double** escaped like this `%252f`. However, it will not replace it with a slash and so the URL ends up looking messy. I avoided this problem by using an underscore for my slash symbol: `/page/LoadPage.aspx?downloads_software` It then replaces the colon with a slash during runtime (the change is not visible in the URL, unfortunately).